# Inconsistent behavior using CSS pseudo-selector :checked to chance div position

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to transition into using pure CSS for interface interactivity and animations. I'm currently working on a website where I want to have a full screen menu drawer drop down when a user hits the menu icon.

I have a checkbox (hidden with a label) positioned in the left of a grid with a z-index of 2 at the top of the screen. My menu is 100vw and 100vh, positioned at -100vh top. When I check the checkbox I want to change the position of the menu to top: 0px.

For some reason although the checkbox appears to be functioning checking the checkbox does not change the position of the menu.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/793b1590a4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mt" />
    <label for="mt" id="mb"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label>
    <div id="ttl"> Website </div>
    <div id="krt"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="ul">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 8vh;
  padding: 1vh 3vw 0 3vw;
  background: #fff;
  grid-template-columns: 10vw 74vw 10vw;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#mt {
  display: none;
}

#mb {
  grid-column: 1;
}

#ttl {
  font-size: 4.5vh;
  grid-column: 2;
  color: #101010;
}

#krt {
  grid-column: 3;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: -100vh;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#ul {
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100vw;
}

#mt:checked~#menu {
  top: 0px;
}
```

I've been troubleshooting this for a while and I made a simpler version which works as intended, but I can't figure out what's breaking the menu between the two. The troubleshooting version looks like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/793b1590a4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-button" />
  <label for="menu-button" class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="ul">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">
      Website
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-button:checked~#menu {
  left: 0px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 5vh;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  left: -300px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#ul {
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#ul>li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

#menu-button {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container {
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why checking the checkbox doesn't change the position of my menu in the first example and does in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example doesn't work because you're using a general sibling combinator (~) in your CSS to select the menu to change the positioning.

```
#mt:checked~#menu {}
```

"The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it follows the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent element."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

---

The second example works because `#menu` follows `#menu-button` AND they have the same parent. In this case #menu is your side menu, and #menu-button is the checkbox.

```
#menu-button:checked~#menu {
  left: 0px;
}
```

The first example won't work for multiple reasons. In this case #menu is your side menu and #mt is your checkbox. But in the HTML they don't share the same parent. Your #menu element is actually a sibling of the #mt checkbox's parent.

```
#mt:checked~#menu {
  top: 0px;
}
```

---

Having said all that, I recommend using Javascript for this functionality. Using CSS handcuffs you into use very specific HTML structures that can match the CSS selectors.

And you also don't have a way to add any accessibility enhancements using this approach. I know these are meant as examples, but as-is they will frustrate a screen reader user, a person with low vision, or a person with low mobility. Nearly 15% of the world's population lives with a disability. So if you're building a website, the breakdown should remain the same: roughly 15% of your site's audience will have some sort of disability.

https://www.who.int/disabilities/world_report/2011/report/en/